# Forcing text not to wrap while preserving minipage format?

Tags: formatting, minipage, cv, wrap

I've been a part of this community ever since taking a class on LaTeX, and have been able to research all of my questions here until now.  This time, however, I need some help.

So I found a nice Résumé format here that I'd like to use.  However, there is one kink left that makes it look ugly.  So my contact info is placed in a `minipage` environment in the top-right corner of the screen, however my email is longer than expected, and thus it wraps to the next line.  However, when I try to use    `rlap` the line starts spilling over to the right instead of being moved to the left.  This is the entire section of code that deals with this.

How do I make my email address move to the left so that it neither wraps nor spills beyond the line?

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{2in}
  \flushleft \footnotesize 
  22 Albatross Lane \\ 
  BC Heights, NY~~22809
\end{minipage}     
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{1.2in}
  \flushright \footnotesize 
  \href{tel:\myphone}{\myphone} \\ %\texttt{ï}~
  \href{mailto:\myemail}{\myemail} % \\ may be unnecessary
\end{minipage}
}\par
\hrulefill
\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image: First way it looks when wrapped]
[image: Second way it looks when not wrapped, but spilling over]

Comment: \rlap overlaps to the right.  \llap overlaps to the left..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `tabular` instead of `minipage`. The fixed width of `minipage` will result in this strange behaviour if the strings get longer than the width. However, without knowing the rest of the document, it is hard to say what the most adequate solution is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\myphone{333-333-3333}
\newcommand\myemail{sampleaddress@uni.edu}
\begin{document}

{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
  22 Albatross Lane \\ 
  BC Heights, NY~~22809
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
  \href{tel:\myphone}{\myphone} \\
  \href{mailto:\myemail}{\myemail}
\end{tabular}%
}%

\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, I did this, and the problem seems to have been fixed!  A minor thing showed up, though, and I can't seem to track down the source of it.  http://imgur.com/a/41vZk .  Now only that bracket is annoying.  But thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: @Coolio2654 I can only guess since I don't see your source code. Search for the string `\{`. Either remove it completely, if there is no closing brace `}`, or remove just the backslash if `{` is needed to limit the effect of some declaration, like `\footnotesize`; in this case there should be a closing brace '}' further down.

Comment: I have done that; the    \{  next to the footnotesize was the culprit.  Now my résumé looks perfect, thank you very much!!